# For Each equivalent in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table, `tblDocs` that has a few columns:

```
DocName varchar(50)
DocLocation int
Active int
DocID int
```

All entries in the table have a `DocName` and `DocLocation`.  `Active` and `DocID` are blank.

What I need to do is for each row in `tblDocs` I need to check the value of `DocLocation` and based on that value I update `tblDocs`, setting the `Active` and `DocID` columns.  I was thinking that I would use a `CASE WHEN` but I'm not sure - I dont know sql very well.  If i were using c# or vb.net it would be the equivalent of a `for each` loop.

```
foreach row as DBRow in tblDocs
    row.active = 1
    row.docID = ID
next
```

How do you do this for SQL Server 2005?

**UPDATE**

From a couple of responses below it sounds like I will use an `UPDATE` Statement.  So I could accomplish this by doing something like

```
UPDATE tblDocs
SET docID = 
    CASE DocLocation
        WHEN 1 THEN --do stuff
        WHEN 3 THEN --do other stuff
```

and this would go through ALL the rows of tblDocs and update the DocID to be based on DocLocation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If i were using c# or vb.net it would be the equivalent of a for each loop.

The trick here is that C# and VB.Net (and javascript, c++, and any other language you're likely used to) are *procedural* languages.  SQL is a *declarative* language.  You describe operations that act on an entire *set* a time.

With that in mind, you want to describe an operation that will `"check the value of DocLocation and based on that value I update tblDocs, setting the Active and DocID columns."`  And to do that you use an `UPDATE` query and case statements:

```
UPDATE tblDocs
SET 
  Active = CASE WHEN DocLocation = 'something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  DocID = CASE WHEN DocLocation = 'something' THEN NULL ELSE DocID END
```

Just a note that this sample also demonstrates how you can use the CASE statement to *unset* a value (set it back to null) or even leave it alone by assigning it itself.  It's also worth nothing that if you really expect to leave a lot of the values alone, you should do that with a WHERE clause instead.

Answer (score 5):

The power of SQL is that you don't need to write loops; you just tell it the things you want to update.  For example, if you wanted to set **all** rows to be active, you'd just do...

```
UPDATE tblDocs
SET Active = 1
```

You want this to depend on the location, so why not...

```
UPDATE tblDocs
SET Active = 1, DocID=42
WHERE DocLocation = 7
```

(Substituting, of course, appropriate values.)  It may be possible to write a single query to update everything, but that will depend on what, specifically, you need to change.

Comment: this sounds like what I need - I updated my question above - can you please clarify if this can be done using a CASE WHEN to SET the value?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a language for data manipulation, don't think about it in terms of traditional control flow structures like loops. Allways try to use the standard SQL operators like INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.

It depends on what values will you use to update the table, but surely you can do it with a simple update clause.

For example:

```
UPDATE tblDocs SET 
  Active = @activeValue,
  DocID = @docIDValue
WHERE DocLocation = @someLocation
```

You could do something similar if your values for the update are coming from another table.

**EDIT** Yes, you can do that with a CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

That concept does not exist in SQL (well, almost true). You should read up on the basic concepts of SQL before you try to use it, it's quite different to procedural programming.

Answer (score -1):

An Update clause will apply on all the rows that satisfy a condition expressed in the where segment

for example:
    -- Will update all rows putting docId = 0
    UPDATE TblDocs SET docId = 0

```
-- Will update all rows satisfying locationId = 1 putting docId = 0
UPDATE TblDocs SET docId = 0 WHERE locationId = 1

-- Will update all rows satisfying locationId = 1 putting docId = locationId + 1
UPDATE TblDocs SET docId = locationId + 1 WHERE locationId = 1
```

Meaning, in the set segment, you can use any logic neccesary to accomplish your task

You can even make an update based on another set of data, maybe in other table

```
UPDATE TblDocs
SET TblDocs.docId = TblLocations.LocId
FROM TblLocations
WHERE TblLocations.docId = TblDocs.docId
```

you can use a cursor, but be aware that almost always you can get a solution using set logic.

here is how to create a cursor

```
DECLARE @DocName CHAR(10), @DocLocation INT, @Active BIT, @DocID INT

DECLARE C CURSOR 
FOR SELECT DocName, DocLocation, Active, DocID FROM TblDocs

OPEN C

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DocName, @DocLocation, @Active, @DocID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    -- do your logic here
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DocName, @DocLocation, @Active, @DocID
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

Comment: I know it's what he asked for in the _literal_ sense, but it's not really what he wants to do and it's entirely the _wrong_ way to go about it.

Comment: The question Title still says foreach equivalent in sql, so that's why i advice on not using... ask microsoft engineers to put out the cursor functionality if it shouldn't be used at all

Comment: I'm not saying _never_ use a cursor:  just that it's utterly backwards for this situation.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i don't emphasized on the update, cause it was already covered when i inserted my answer, but in any case, i have edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score -2):

Use a cursor: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1599

When you need to check a value in that row, and then update it based on something I find that cursors work best. However beware, there is performance issues if the table is really large or any joins are done in a cursor.